# Doctrine query subset of one-to-many relation

Tags: sql, doctrine, one-to-many, dql

I ve the following tables:

```
mysql> show columns from Person;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
|guid | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> show columns from Person_Func;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Person_id | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| Func_id   | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
mysql> show columns from Func;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entry       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| description | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| Guid    | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Symfony class Person contains one-to-many relation to Func (one Person - several Funcs) using join table Person_Func. I want to query for Person, who has got a number of Funcs -
steve (a, b , c); john (a, b, d); ele (b, d) - and I query for (a, b) functions and steve and john should be returned.

Right now I am just iterating thru all the persons and querying for Functions  - that's very-very slow. Could you please help me?

**UPD**
I have succeeded with

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.guid from (select p.guid, f.entry from Person p, Person_Func jt, Func f where p.Guid = jt.person_id and jt.func_id = f.guid and f.entry in ('A', 'B')) as d1,
(select p.guid, f.entry from Person p, Person_Func jt, Func f where p.Guid = jt.person_id and jt.func_id = f.guid and f.entry in ('A', 'B')) as d2 
where d1.guid=d2.guid and d1.entry != d2.entry
```

But I think that that's a not a good idea, yes?

Comment: Any luck finding out the best practice for this?

Answer (score 1):

Linking Person and Person_Func with `JOIN` is a cleaner way of doing it:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Person p INNER JOIN Person_Func pf ON p.id = pf.person_id
              INNER JOIN Person_Func pf2 ON p.id = pf2.person_id
WHERE
    pf.func_id = 'a' 
    AND pf2.func_id = 'b'
```

Here you have the [SQLFiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3bf11/4)